React-scripts token error on yarn start in 5 year old project — works on other machines
I’m encountering an issue with a 5 yeas old React project where react-scripts is unable to identify tokens, leading to an error. The project runs perfectly fine on the production server and other developers’ machines, but I’m facing this issue on my system.
I am trying to avoid modifying the package.json files since the code works elsewhere without problems.
Here’s the problematic command I’m using:
YARN PORT=5555 NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider doppler run -- craco start

this build command works without any issues:
doppler run -- env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider craco --max-old-space-size=8192 build

{
    "name": "skillstrainer-admin-client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@apollo/client": "^3.4.10",
      "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^41.1.0",
      "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.2.0",
      "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
      "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
      "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.0",
      "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.3",
      "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.3",
      "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.2",
      "@progress/kendo-react-pdf": "^5.5.0",
      "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.1.1",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
      "async_hooks": "^1.0.0",
      "axios": "^0.21.1",
      "base-64": "^1.0.0",
      "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
      "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
      "boxicons": "^2.0.9",
      "browser-monads": "^1.0.0",
      "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632",
      "daisyui": "^2.11.0",
      "dateformat": "^5.0.2",
      "easyinvoice": "^2.3.3",
      "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
      "formik": "2.2.9",
      "grapesjs": "^0.20.1",
      "grapesjs-blocks-basic": "^1.0.1",
      "grapesjs-mjml": "^0.6.0",
      "grapesjs-plugin-forms": "^2.0.5",
      "grapesjs-preset-webpage": "^1.0.1",
      "grapesjs-react": "^4.0.1",
      "graphql": "^15.5.2",
      "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
      "json2csv": "^6.0.0-alpha.2",
      "jszip": "^3.10.1",
      "lodash": "^4.17.21",
      "moment": "^2.29.1",
      "mongoose": "^7.5.0",
      "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
      "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
      "query-string": "^7.0.1",
      "react": "^17.0.2",
      "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
      "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.4",
      "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
      "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
      "react-data-table-component": "^7.4.5",
      "react-datepicker": "^4.5.0",
      "react-datetime-picker": "^3.4.3",
      "react-dnd": "^15.1.1",
      "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^15.1.2",
      "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
      "react-drag-drop-files": "^2.3.7",
      "react-draggable": "^4.4.6",
      "react-dropzone": "^11.5.3",
      "react-fileupload-progress": "^0.5.0",
      "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
      "react-pdf": "^9.1.1",
      "react-qr-code": "^2.0.7",
      "react-quiz-component": "^0.3.9",
      "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
      "react-router": "^5.2.0",
      "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
      "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
      "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
      "react-scroll-into-view": "^1.12.0",
      "react-select": "^5.3.2",
      "react-simple-timefield": "^3.2.5",
      "react-time-picker": "^4.4.4",
      "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
      "react-uuid": "^2.0.0",
      "recharts": "^2.5.0",
      "recoil": "^0.6.1",
      "redux": "^4.1.2",
      "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
      "sty": "^0.6.1",
      "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
      "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
      "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "PORT=5555 NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider doppler run -- craco start",
      "staging": "REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV=staging PORT=5555 craco start",
      "staging_openssl": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV=staging PORT=5555 craco start",
      "prod": "REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV=production PORT=5555 craco start",
      "dev": "REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV=dev PORT=5555 craco start",
      "build": "craco --max-old-space-size=8192 build",
      "build-staging": "REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV=staging craco --max-old-space-size=4096 build",
      "build-prod": "REACT_APP_BUILD_ENV=production craco --max-old-space-size=4096 build",
      "build-raw": "craco --max-old-space-size=8192 build",
      "test": "craco test"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
      "postcss": "^7.0.39",
      "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
    },
    "resolutions": {
      "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001632"
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }
}


things i have tried to resolve this error:

update react-scripts to latest
yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env --dev#
adding options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'] } to craco config.


Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s.

The error is You may need an additional loader to handle...。May be your babel-loader can't handle the symbol ??;
@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator can transforms the nullish coalescing operator(??), although this plugin is included in @babel/preset-env, in ES2020, you can try add this plugin to your craco config;
If this project runs perfectly fine on the production server and other developers’ machines, check the Node.js version used by other developers and ensure that yours matches, removenode_modules and reinstall again.

I have removed and install node_modules multiple times but the error persists. I am using the same node version as one of the colleague.
